# External disk doesn’t appear in /dev/

Tags: usb, udev, usb-drive

I have an external (USB-2.0) hard drive. Today I couldn’t mount it after plugging to my computer. When I look in /dev/

```
$ ls /dev/sd*
```

There is no new disk, only sda and sdb with their partitions, which are two local 3.5" hard drives. However, when I took a look at dmesg, there were lines telling that disk appeared as /dev/sdc.

```
[542880.810341] usb 7-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 15 using ehci-pci
[542880.896004] usb 7-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2329
[542880.896007] usb 7-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=11, SerialNumber=5
[542880.896008] usb 7-1.1: Product: StoreJet Transcend
[542880.896010] usb 7-1.1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[542880.896011] usb 7-1.1: SerialNumber: 322549CB7013
[542880.896391] usb-storage 7-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[542880.896422] scsi21 : usb-storage 7-1.1:1.0
[542881.917895] scsi 21:0:0:0: Direct-Access     StoreJet Transcend        2AJ1 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[542881.917995] sd 21:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[542881.918635] sd 21:0:0:0: [sdc] 1250263727 512-byte logical blocks: (640 GB/596 GiB)
[542881.919636] sd 21:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[542881.919639] sd 21:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[542881.920633] sd 21:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[542881.920634] sd 21:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[542881.923253] sd 21:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[542881.923254] sd 21:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[542881.966710]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 sdc3 < sdc5 sdc6 > sdc4
[542881.970736] sd 21:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[542881.970739] sd 21:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[542881.970742] sd 21:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

It cannot be other disk or a flash card because I compared dmesg output right before plugging in external drive and after that.

How can that be?

My system is Gentoo amd64 with eudev.

---

[cat /proc/partitions](http://pastie.org/pastes/8684169/text)

[udevd --debug](http://pastie.org/pastes/8684197/text)

Comment: You're sure that these are the last `dmesg` lines and that the USB device didn't vanish for some reason in the meantime? Have you checked the output of `cat /proc/partitions` to see if the kernel sees it?

Comment: Better run `udev monitor` and post the output. That's more deterministic than the dmesg output.

Comment: @martin-von-wittich /dev/sdc1-6 are in partition list (see above)

Comment: @elias-probst I’ve added output of `udevd --debug`.